# filling combobox with data from php database on button click and load selected value from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, combobox

I have php form that get loaded in HTML on button click using js

```
        <button id="edituser" type="submit" onclick="toggle_visibility('c');"  style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 74px;">
        <img src="images/edituser.png" alt="">
        </button><br><br>
```

js code is :

```
if(document.getElementById("c").id == id)
{
      e.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("a").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("b").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("edituser").style.backgroundImage="url('images/edit_user_hover.png')";
}
```

The Php form with combobox is given below:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="display:none"  id="c" > 
            <form action=""   method="post"  >
        <br><br>
                <br>

        <select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style=" width:150px;" onChange="this.form.submit();">
                <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "val";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $arr = array();

                    $sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_user  ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



                 ?>
        <option value="">-select user-</option>
            <?php                   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $arr[] = $row;
                               ?>
                <option value="<?php  echo  $row["id"]; ?>" <?php if($_POST["id"]== $row["id"]) {?>  selected="selected" <?php } ?>>  
                <?php  echo  $row["id"];?>
                </option>
            <?php 
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        header('Location: webservices.php');
}

mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
        </select>

                <br><br>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="First Name*">
                <br>
                <br><br><br>

                <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Last Name*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Phone*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="company_id" name="company_id" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Company ID*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="register_on" name="register_on" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Register On*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <button name="edituser" id="edituser" type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 45px;" >
                <img src="images/save.png" alt="">

                </button>
                <button type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 75px;">
                <img src="images/cancel.png" alt="">
                </button>

                </form> 
                </div>
```

Here the functionality that i require on button click the combobox should load values from data base then on select value from combobox the form should load values from database
I am pretty new so please help ?the combobox is not loading values from database on button click ..and how to make from get loaded from database on value combobox selection ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the PHP code for DB connection should be written in another file and include it here. It's the best practice. Then use the following code to retrieve the combo box data. Take the result of your query to an array as such.

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($teamQuery)) {
     $results[] = $row;
}
```

Then iterate on the array on the place where you want to echo the data.

```
<select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style=" width:150px;" onChange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">-select user-</option>
    <?php
      foreach($results as $key => $row){
           echo "<option value='".$row['option_value']."'>".$row['option_name']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
</select>
```

You should echo an option to get it drawn in the HTML file. And for your reference, The method you are using to show hide data is not recommended. The page will load faster if you stop retrieving data on the initial page load. Just bind an ajax function on to the button and then, on the button click retrieve the combo box data and show it. Then process any other data along the way.

Comment: I have initial blank loaded page with button on it .Then on button click hidden div shows form using javascript .I want hidden from with combobox should show database values loaded in combobox.then on selecting values on combobox the html form should load the corresponding values from db

Comment: Then my answer should work for you! you take the values from the DB and echo it to as options. Then on button click shows combo box data. on data change it will run your js functions.

Comment: ok it is working ...How to load selected id data in combobox to html form

Comment: Write an ajax get to load data from the DB on change of the combo box. return the result as a json string from PHP then, iterate it using javascript to load it to html elements.